# How to "Run a single Flink job on YARN " by rest API?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

From the  Flink official document we know that we can "Run a single Flink job on YARN " by the command below ,my question is can we  "Run a single Flink job on YARN " by Rest API, and got the application API ?

```
./bin/flink run -m yarn-cluster -yn 2 ./examples/batch/WordCount.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

See the (somewhat deceptively named) [Monitoring REST API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/monitoring/rest_api.html). You can use the `/jars/upload` request to send your (fat/uber) jar to the cluster. This returns back an id, that you can use with the `/jars/:jarid/run` request to start your job.

If you also need to start up the cluster, then you're currently (AFAIK) going to need to write some Java code to start a cluster on YARN. There are two source files in Flink that do this same thing:

- [ProgramDeployer.java](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/0ab1549f52f1f544e8492757c6b0d562bf50a061/flink-table/flink-sql-client/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/table/client/gateway/local/ProgramDeployer.java) Used by the Flink Table API.
- [CliFrontEnd.java](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/a8434d686473a088a876967dc2fe9b5dee0e3169/flink-clients/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/client/cli/CliFrontend.java) Used by the command line tool.

Comment: The prerequisite for the Rest API is the cluster already exists, however for "Run a single Flink job on YARN " ,there is no flink cluster  instance exists , as the cluster is created with the job. see details : https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/ops/deployment/yarn_setup.html

Comment: Updated to include some info on code refs for starting Flink on a cluster, sorry about missing that point in your question.